# Android : Bitmap : How to save canvas with green background in android?

Tags: android, bitmap

I am using Bitmap for creating digital signature Image. While storing the Signature on device only signature got stored with black background. I want green background with signature.

Here it's my Bitmap code

```
 // Bitmap View
public class MyView extends View implements OnClickListener
{
    public int height;
    public int width;       
    private Bitmap  mBitmap;        
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint; 

    public MyView(Context c) 
    {
        super(c);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);   
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) 
    {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);  
        Wid = w;
        Ht = h; 
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);            
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);       

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas)
    { 

        canvas.drawColor(0xFFFFFFFF);       
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint); 

        // onclick listner for SAVE button
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                //capture the image  
                try {                    
                    saveAsJpg(mBitmap);     
                    startActivity(new Intent(Paint.this, SignatureActivity.class));
                    finish();
                } catch (IOException e) {                   
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }  
        });             
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4; 

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) 
    { 
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        System.out.println("---- " +mX);
    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) 
    { 
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }
    private void touch_up() 
    { 
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {

        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;

        }
        return true;
    }
```

I can able to see the green background while creating signature, but it is saved on black blackground. please help me out, Thanks in advance

Comment: post the saveAsJpg() method code....

Comment: @rahul we need to set canvas background in `onSizeChanged` Method because Bitmap that you have used to save it have use `canvas` of `onSizeChanged`,And you have set Canvas color in `onDraw` so it will show , but it has not apply to Bitmap .Check my updated code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@rahul You can also use this in `onDraw`

```
 canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Please Check update of my code

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);            
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);  
    mCanvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try change this in onDraw

```
 canvas.drawColor(0xFFFF0000);
```

Comment: But its not saving with green background rather it storing with black background color. Please help me out. Where I am going wrong dont know... Thanks Sachi

Answer (score 1):

`canvas.drawColor` changes the canvas but not the bitmap you can fill the bitmap with

```
bitmap.eraseColor(color);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code for Saving the File

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Yourpath);
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, fos);
```

As you have posted that you want to save this will work.